# Rendered File Cannot be Opened

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

I tried to render this project of mine, but the output file is just a blank one. [image]

Comment: Did you render a single image or an animation? Because you chose an MP4 as output format.

Comment: I rendered it as an animation but the output file cannot even be opened.

Comment: Does your file have an *.mp4 extension that's not visible or is there simply no extension? Windows doesn't know automatically how to open files without extension - and honestly this paper sheet symbol just looks like what Windows shows when it doesn't know what kind of file it is.